# AngularJS directive $destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular app setup with `ng-view`. In one view, in addition to the view itself, there is also a component inside that view that is dynamically loaded. This component is a directive that essentially compiles the contents so the contents can be further hooked with other directives (which it is). The content inside that component is compiled using `$compile(element.contents())(scope);`.

As an example:

```html
<ng-view>
  <viewer doc="getDocument()">
  </viewer>
</ng-view>
```

```js
angular.directive('viewer', ['$compile', '$anchorScroll', function($compile, $anchorScroll) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        var doc = scope.$eval(attrs.doc);
        if (!doc)
          return ""
        return doc.html;
      },
      function(value) {
        element.html(value);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    );
  };
}]);
```

My problem is when I switch routes, I essentially switch `ng-view` or `viewer`'s content. The problem I'm having is a memory leak, where in other directives inside the `viewer` hooks to events and do not clean up when the route is changed.

One such example is as follows:

```
angular.directive('i18n', ['$rootScope', 'LocaleService', function($rootScope, LocaleService) {
  var cleanup;
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var originalText = element.text();
      element.text(LocaleService.getTranslation(originalText, attrs.locale));
      cleanup = $rootScope.$on('locale-changed', function(locale) {
        element.text(LocaleService.getTranslation(originalText, attrs.locale || locale));
      });
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log("destroy");
        cleanup();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

How do I have it so that these events are properly cleaned up?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The i18n example you provided would work if you only ever used it once.

I don't think you should be doing the event binding inside the compile function. You can do it inside the link function instead:

```
angular.directive('i18n', ['$rootScope', 'LocaleService', function($rootScope, LocaleService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var cleanup;
      var originalText = element.text();
      element.text(LocaleService.getTranslation(originalText, attrs.locale));
      cleanup = $rootScope.$on('locale-changed', function(locale) {
        element.text(LocaleService.getTranslation(originalText, attrs.locale || locale));
      });
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log("destroy");
        cleanup();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Alternatively, you could bind the event on the child scope itself, and use `$broadcast` on the `$rootScope` to trigger it. That way the event will automatically be garbage collected when the scope is destroyed:

```
angular.directive('i18n', ['$rootScope', 'LocaleService', function($rootScope, LocaleService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var originalText = element.text();
      setElText();
      function setElText(locale){
        element.text(LocaleService.getTranslation(originalText, attrs.locale || locale));
      }
      scope.$on('locale-changed', setElText);
    }
  };
}]);

$rootScope.$broadcast('locale-change', 'en-AU');
```

Comment: My issue is that new i18n directive shows up as I navigate around. So it is not just used once. Consider a case where I have a `<i18n>Last updated</i18n>` in each `<ng-view>`. That would be loaded each time I change `ng-view`

Comment: Sorry what i meant by the first sentence is that your current implementation would only clean up the last event listener bound. since the `cleanup` var is declared in the 'factory' portion of the directive. The two samples i've provided should do what you want.

Comment: Agreed. That makes sense. An additional step is needed to make this work completely. Refer to: https://github.com/shuhaowu/osumo/blob/master/static/js/develop/controllers/viewer.js#L55

Comment: @Clark Pan it seems like you use _$scope_ instead of _scope_ in the second example.