# Angularjs use function keys as shortcuts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox, I want to use **function keys(<kbd>f1</kbd>-<kbd>f12</kbd>)** as their shortcut key. For example every time I press <kbd>f4</kbd> I want to make element focused.

```
<input type="text" shortcutkey="f14">
```

shortcutkey its just an example.

something like this.

Also, browsers use these functions keys, is there any way to disable the keys for them with code.

Comment: not sure if "f4" will work, the key probably have some keycode as well. `event.preventDefault();` should be able to disable default browser behavior though. Else there is always the possibility to try and remove the functions from the window object (like `window.onhelp = () => false ` to disable F1's default help function) but I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: @JonasJohansson I see the customer form on a video, they use all function keys on their forms except f5.so I'm looking for a way to create a form with function shortcut keys.

Comment: I see, then maybe `keyup`events would work better. I'm not sure how ng-shortcutkey works exactly but if you get the event back somehow and can use `event.preventDefault();`or perhaps also ´event.stopPropagation();`on the events it should work fine I think.

Comment: @JonasJohansson ng-shortcut key is just an example

Comment: Avoid using the prefix `ng-` for custom directives. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core AngularJS directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the directory so in its `link` function it will listen to `keyup` event on the document and if the key is the value of the attribute, focus the element. Like this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {})
  .directive('shortcutkey', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        shortcutkey: '@',
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        function onKeyUp(e) {
          if (e.code.toLowerCase() === scope.shortcutkey.toLowerCase()) {
            element[0].focus();
          }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

        /* because we added a listener we want to remove it once the element - the directive's "owner" has been removed from the DOM, to avoid unnecessary listeners
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203143/863110
        */
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" shortcutkey="f4">
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/xixovag/3/edit?html,js,output

I don't think you can prevent from the browser to act to that event though.

As @georgeawg mention `ng-` prefix is a convention of angular's directives such as `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Although, this will work, people who will read the code will think that this directive comes from angular.

Comment: I much appreciate your Answer Mosh Feu. Everything works Great

Comment: Glad to hear :) Do you understand what the code does? It's important to me that you'll understand it..

Comment: Avoid using the prefix `ng-` for custom directives. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core AngularJS directives.